# Can't set apn_write permissions on a COSU (corporate owned single use) androiddevice

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is it at all possible for a deviceadmin app provisioned on a [COSU](https://developer.android.com/work/cosu.html) device to remove for example the apn settings?

Currently we are doing it via root, but we wan't to move our app to non-rooted devices.
Doing it via the contentresolver leads to permission denied

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://telephony/carriers");

context.getContentResolver().delete(uri, null, null);
```

We defined the permission in our manifest file, but to no avail

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_APN_SETTINGS" />
```

We were wondering if there is a way using the devicepolicymanager or something to grant us those permissions as a deviceadmin on a COSU provisioned device?

Comment: My guess is that's a system permission.  Which means you either need to be preinstalled as a trusted system app by the OEM, or you need to root your device and install yourself as a trusted system app.

Comment: yes, you are correct. It is a system permission, but I was wondering if a COSU app could in any way elevate itself or bypass those permissiones.

I guess not...

Comment: Not that I know of.  I wrote a kiosk once-  while device policy ownership let me lock down the tablet fairly well I still needed a lot of system permissions to do various things.  If that company had been successful we would have eventually made our own firmware image to copy onto devices, at that point you can have the image install you in the proper place.